# MySQL select one to many

Tags: mysql, database, select

**table1:**

```
PRP_ID  |     NAME      
----------------------
100     |   something_100        
101     |   something_101         
102     |   something_102
```

**table2:**

```
ADN_ID |     NAME      
----------------------
11     |   thing_11        
22     |   thing_22         
33     |   thing_33
```

**table3:**

```
ID |     ADN_ID   |  PRP_ID   | VALUE
----------------------------------------
1  |       11     |    100    | YES
2  |       22     |    100    | YES
3  |       11     |    101    | NO
4  |       22     |    101    | YES
5  |       33     |    102    | YES
```

This is my database structure. 
I would like to select `PRP_ID` from last table where `ADN_ID` `IN(11,22)` and `WHERE VALUE = YES` for both ADN_ID

It should by very simple but I don't have idea how to do it.

---

```
SELECT PRP_ID
FROM  table3
WHERE ADN_ID IN(11,22)
AND VALUE = YES
GROUP BY PRP_ID
```

This won't work because it checks only ADN_ID 11 value

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `having` clause:

```
SELECT PRP_ID
FROM  table3
WHERE ADN_ID IN (11,22) AND VALUE = 'YES'
GROUP BY PRP_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ADN_ID) = 2;
```

Comment: Thats what I ment! :) Thank You